# Remove shadow / glow on fusion tables polyline or polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have never seen the drop shadow/glow on polylines or polygons from the Google Maps API, except with the Fusion Tables. How can this be removed?

The page linked seems to be the most detailed documentation for styling, but nothing talks about shadows/glow as far as I saw.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/style

The Shadow:

[image]

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
         select: '',
        from: 'tableid',
    },
    styles: [{
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: '#5A91EB',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 2,
        },
    }],
    suppressInfoWindows:true,
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid currently it can't be removed

Comment: You can make a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/)